# Using FreeRADIUS with Eduroam

Tags: freeradius

My friend

I am a beginner in freeRADIUS, My goal is to simulate freeRADIUS with Eduroam. Some of the internal resources are helpful, but some processes are a bit difficult for me. Is there anyone out there who has a clear and simple explanation of how to implement it in virtual situations? I need to understand what's going on with it and what kind of configuration we should have.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want simulate Freeradius with eduroam? Like a partner institute (IdP and SP) or like a roaming operator? If your choice is the first, more precisely IdP, you can follow this https://wiki.freeradius.org/guide/eduroam.